# Use count on lists with lapply and return list gives error

Tags: r

Creating the list.

```
Location <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c")
  Music <- c("pop", "rock", "house", "funk", "electro", "swing", "metal", "punk", "indie")
  Food <- c("burger", "pizza", "fries", "spaghetti", "pancakes", "hotdog", "pasta", "kebab", "chicken")
  
  Events <- tibble(Location, Music, Food)
  
  Events_List <- split(Events, Location)
```

Now applying the function:

```
lapply(Events_List, count(Music, Food))
```

Gives an Error:

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Why is that?

The expected outcome would be three tibbles similar to the following, but one for each Location:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 10
  Music   pancakes spaghetti fries chicken pasta burger kebab pizza hotdog
  <chr>      <int>     <int> <int>   <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int>  <int>
1 electro        1         0     0       0     0      0     0     0      0
2 funk           0         1     0       0     0      0     0     0      0
3 house          0         0     1       0     0      0     0     0      0
4 indie          0         0     0       1     0      0     0     0      0
5 metal          0         0     0       0     1      0     0     0      0
6 pop            0         0     0       0     0      1     0     0      0
7 punk           0         0     0       0     0      0     1     0      0
8 rock           0         0     0       0     0      0     0     1      0
9 swing          0         0     0       0     0      0     0     0      1
```

I am glad for every hint, regards.

Even better would be a solution, where i don't have to create a list before and still get a tibble for each Location.

Expected outcome would be something like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Music Food       n
  <chr> <chr>  <int>
1 house fries      1
2 pop   burger     1
3 rock  pizza      1

$b
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Music   Food          n
  <chr>   <chr>     <int>
1 electro pancakes      1
2 funk    spaghetti     1
3 swing   hotdog        1

$c
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Music Food        n
  <chr> <chr>   <int>
1 indie chicken     1
2 metal pasta       1
3 punk  kebab       1
```

But there should also be a column added to each tibble, that shows which Location it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax. Try :

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(Events_List, function(x) count(x, Music, Food))
```

Or without anonymous function

```
lapply(Events_List, count, Music, Food)
```

---

If you don't want to do split it beforehand, you can use `count` and `group_split`.

```
Events %>% count(Location, Music, Food) %>% group_split(Location)
```

Comment: First two work. Your solution without creating a list beforehand doesn't give me a tibble for each Location, though.

Comment: tibble for each Location? I updated the post with the output that I am getting based on your data. If you expect something different can you update your post to include that?

Comment: I edited it with your first solutions. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: I see. so you still want them as separate dataframes, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
res <- Map(function(x){transform(x, n = ave(Music, Food, FUN = length))}, 
    split(data.frame(Location, Music, Food, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), Location))
```

Tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(Location, Music, Food) %>% 
  group_split(., Location) %>% 
  map(., count, Music, Food)
```

Data:

```
Location <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c")
Music <- c("pop", "rock", "house", "funk", "electro", "swing", "metal", "punk", "indie")
Food <- c("burger", "pizza", "fries", "spaghetti", "pancakes", "hotdog", "pasta", "kebab", "chicken")
```